# Combining jQuery Sortable and Drop Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, function

Basically I have a draggable list which is connected with a sortable list. Works great except I need some sort of Drop event which I can use to change the list item after its dropped into the sortable list.

This works with .draggable -> .droppable but is there a fix for draggable -> .sortable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured out, turns out there is a receive event which is the same as drop for the droppable.

```
$('.selector').sortable({
  receive: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Comment: If I'm using the draggable with the helper: clone option is there a way to target the items I'm dropping. When I use the ui.item it changes the old item, while ui.helper doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I have the same issue. I am unable to target the items I'm dropping. I tried both 'stop' on the draggable and 'receive' on the sortable.

Comment: The only way I was able to do it with 'clone was by giving a class name to the draggable container and then using jquery to target that class name in the sortable container.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you use 2 sortable lists that are connected ? Then you can use the stop event

You can connect 2 lists by doing:

```
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
}).disableSelection();
```

And then use the stop event

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

You can then change the dropped element by doing ui. (don't know this by heart but with the draggable plugin its ui.draggable)