# Dragging and Sorting javascript/jqueryq

Tags: jquery

I am implementing a drag and drop code, what I have at the moment is 6 dragable and dropable images, What I am tryin to do is when for example image a is dragged over image b the swap places leaving the rest alone,

take a look - http://jsfiddle.net/kommandoss/YuRpU/2/

any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many sortable Jquery plugins. The JQ UI Sortable and Dragable seem to have a conflict in version 1.7. Not sure if they resolved that in the subsequent releases.

Here is a fiddle I found that does some of what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/strategycon/GbVvW/4/

I haven't read through all the code, but it uses the sortable UI. Perhaps you can glean something from that.

Here is an example that combines both:
http://jsbin.com/acobi/3

Here is a blog post about how to combine them:
http://www.fraggednation.com/blog/JQuery-using-a-Sortable-and-Droppable-objects-together-374

or this one on combining:
http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/11/23/combining-selectables-and-draggables-using-jquery-ui/

Here on on the overflow a guy said he fixed it by doing this:

```
$('.selector').sortable({
  receive: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323409/combining-jquery-sortable-and-drop-event)

Answer (score 0):

Just use sortable
http://jsfiddle.net/YuRpU/5/

Comment: thanks, this works nicely when swapping left to right but not when up and down, do you know what I could add to make it work both ways?